# How to call different Function under module.exports

Tags: node.js

I have a Helper.js file. Under this file mentioned the Code for doing stuff with Database.

```
Helper.js FILE
module.exports.test1 = function(req, res){
    ABC.find({}).exec(function(err, post) {
        if(post.length == '0'){
            res.send({'No Data'});
        }else if(err){
            res.send({'Error'});
        }else {
            res.send({'data':post});
        }
    });
}

module.exports.test2 = function(req, res){
    ABC.find({}).exec(function(err, post) {
        if(post.length == '0'){
            res.send({'No Data'});
        }else if(err){
            res.send({'Error'});
        }else {
            res.send({'data':post});
        }
    });
}
```

Now In My getter.js File I am calling the function Like this And it Works Perfectly fine For me i.e Code Like this

```
Getter.js FILE
var helper = require('./helper');
router.get('/gettest1', helper.test1);
router.get('/gettest2', helper.test2);
```

Now my Question is How to Create functions under Single Module.exports???
I also researched and tried this Kind of Code but getting Error i.e "Route.get() requires callback functions but got an [object Undefined]
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as get]"
My Modified Code of Helper.js File is

```
Helper.js FILE
    module.exports = {
    test1 = function(req, res){
        ABC.find({}).exec(function(err, post) {
            if(post.length == '0'){
                res.send({'No Data'});
            }else if(err){
                res.send({'Error'});
            }else {
                res.send({'data':post});
            }
        });
    },
    test2 = function(req, res){
        ABC.find({}).exec(function(err, post) {
            if(post.length == '0'){
                res.send({'No Data'});
            }else if(err){
                res.send({'Error'});
            }else {
                res.send({'data':post});
            }
        });
    }
    };
```

And In my getter.js file Code like this

```
Getter.js FILE
var helper = require('./helper');
router.get('/gettest1', helper.test1());
router.get('/gettest2', helper.test2());
```

Please Share the best approach for doing this kind of stuff

Comment: I don’t think you understand how module.exports works. Your first approach is creating functions under module.exports. Nothing wrong with your first method. Just different ways to do it.

Comment: I answer The Question. Actually, I have to call an Object instead of Function

Answer (score 0):

It's Done. Main Problem is On getter.js File Calling Wrong Format i.e
Not This Way

```
Getter.js FILE
var helper = require('./helper');
router.get('/gettest1', helper.test1());
router.get('/gettest2', helper.test2());
```

Correct Way is

```
Getter.js FILE
var helper = require('./helper');
router.get('/gettest1', helper.test1);//As it is an object not function
router.get('/gettest2', helper.test2);//As it is an object not function
```